# Using fixed QGIS modeler vector input parameter?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I'm writing a QGIS (v3) model and I'd like to have a vector layer input fixed to a specific shapefile. This way, every time I run the model, I don't need to select the file.

Is this possible?

Right now, when I choose a vector layer input, it does not let me select which file to use.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. Just found out that in order to fix the input for a algorithm, I must set it in the algorithm dialog. I was a bit confused and trying to do this in the input 'box'.