# Using fixed vector layer parameter in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

How can I set my input layers to be called as defaults is QGIS Modeller?

I am sure I am missing something simple but as it is I need to pull them down from the list every time.  I want to set them as permanent calls.

[Using fixed QGIS modeler vector input parameter?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302604) seems to deal with files but it doesn't make sense to me either.

Answer (score 1):

If the input layer is stored in the same place on your system then you can point to it in the algorithm box that needs its which removes the need for an input box:

[image]

Comment: Except that the layers I am trying to call are not built from files, they are built from a PostGIS database.  What then?